# XCode 7.3 AutoLayout - Constraints not looking correct in Preview

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, constraints

I don't understand why the constraints aren't looking correctly in the preview panel. Any tips? Any best videos on constraints with Xcode, I learn best by watching. Both are 3.5 inches.

Thanks for your feedback.

[image]

Comment: Seems the `constraints` you gave to the date works fine. The symbol just above it misplaces the date since the `top constraint` of date is connected to the `bottom` of the symbol. Please check the constraints on the symbol. You may find tutorials by [Ray Wenderlich](https://www.raywenderlich.com/118998/video-tutorial-intro-to-auto-layout-series-introduction)

Comment: For such grid view, I recommend to use UICollectionView, it's better performance and no need to add so many constrains and setups by yourself

Comment: MudOnTime: Indeed the UICollectionView is a good idea. @Matthews: Thanks for the video.

Comment: `UICollectionView` is always the best choice when the view has multiple rows and columns. It takes care of everything and we don't need to control it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not looking for UICollectionView. I've admitted it's a plausible solution but isn't addressing what I have asked in the manner in which I have asked. UIStackViews are my best option. Thanks again to the guy who gave me the videos, they are the best help with constraints and layouts etc.

Answer solved.